# Vector Art Tool: Size, Position, Shapes, Symbols

Tags: 2d, tools, vector-art

I'm looking for a vector art tool for gameart, similar to Flash, but preferably free. It just needs the following capabilities:

- Create vector images (can scale up/down without losing quality)
- Specify shape X/Y to the pixel (eg. set the X to 24.1, like in Flash)
- Draw primitive shapes (square/circle/triangle) with border and colour (or gradient)
- Specify shape width/height in precise pixels
- Export to PNG

Flash can do all this, but it's expensive (and heavy to install). Is there a free alternative that I can use?

This is NOT for pixely, pixel-style art.

Comment: Does **Google SketchUp** provide all these features for you (I don't know if it does, which is why I'm typing this in a Comment instead of an Answer)?  http://sketchup.google.com/

Comment: You might be able to bend SketchUp to do that. Set the camera to Parallel perspective with a top down view. Otherwise it looks like this is a request for a 2D program. Maybe something like [http://inkscape.org/](http://inkscape.org/) I'll post that as an answer if that works for you :)

Comment: It definitely is a request for a 2d program, since he basically wants the same features as flash provides. So Inkscape would be a better choice than SketchUp

Comment: @bummzack +1 for Inkscape!

Comment: I used Inkscape for one project. Instead of converting to PNG, I kept the file as SVG and used Qts SVG classes to render it to texture at startup time.

Comment: How about getting these as answers instead of comments? Upvotes where upvotes are deserved. Yes, I want a 2D tool, not a 3D tool.

Comment: Also: can you do tweening-style animations with InkScape? i.e. rotate over X frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is the answer! I downloaded it last night, it does seem like a really nice program. I don't know a lot about it, but I'm fairly sure it does all the things you want it to.

Comment: Does it support animation?

Comment: For integrated animation, it looks like it's "in the works". There are however a few tutorials ([here's one](http://www.nuxified.org/article/create_video_animations_inkscape_imagemagick_and_ffmpeg)) out there for using inkscape with other programs to create animations.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape: http://inkscape.org/
Seriously, how does everyone know about Sketch-Up but not Inkscape?! It's like the only good free SVG editor ffs!

Answer (score 0):

The web [alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/) is a good place to find alternatives similar to a program.

These are the free alternatives to inkscape, that seems to be the free vector graphics editor reference:

- [OpenOffice - Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html)
- [Xara Xtreme](http://xaraxtreme.org/)
- [gpaint](http://www.gnu.org/software/gpaint/)
- [Skencil](http://www.skencil.org/)
- [Ella](http://ella.tuxfamily.org/)